# GraphFrames SLF4J not available

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graphframes

I am running Scala 2.10.4 with Spark 1.5.0-cdh5.5.2 and am getting the following error when running a GraphFrames job:

scala

```
> val g = GraphFrame(v, e)
error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in Logging.class refers to type LazyLogging
in package com.typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling Logging.class.
```

I am starting my spark-shell with the following command:

`spark-shell --jars /data/spark-jars/scalalogging-slf4j_2.10-1.1.0.jar,/data/spark-jars/graphframes-0.2.0-spark1.5-s_2.10.jar`

I have tried different versions of scalalogging, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for the help.